# How to add tags to S3 buckets from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
bucket_name    tags
name1          tag1
name2          tag2
name3          tag3
```

I want to use the above to insert tags into the respective s3 bucket. How can I do this using boto3?

Comment: Please provide your existing python code, and explain why it does not work. Any errors?

Comment: I don't have any python code. I literally have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_tags = {'bucket_name': 'tag',...}
for bucket, tag in bucket_tags.items():
  response = s3_client.put_bucket_tagging(
                 Bucket = bucket,
                 Tagging={
                     'TagSet': [
                         {
                            'Key': 'mykey',
                            'Value': tag
                         },
                      ]
                  },
            )
```

Comment: I just used dictionary instead of a dataframe.